# Sending user POST input using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

how do i send the following request using POST method?

```
lun = document.getElementById("lun").value;
lp = document.getElementById("lp").value;
url = "lun="+lun+"&lp="+lp;
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("login").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("login").innerHTML="Loading";
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",'login.php?'+url,true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: xmlhttp.open("POST"...               And sending data in the "send" call.

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP method to use, such as "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", etc. Ignored for non-HTTP(S) URLs.

```
 xmlhttp.open("POST",'login.php',true);
 xmlhttp.send(url);
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: You can send the data separate from the URL in the xmlhttp.send() call.

Answer (score 1):

for post

try this

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","login.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(url);
```

Here is the demo http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_post2

Comment: Thank you! the xhr.setrequestheader solved it, can you explain whats the purpose of it?

Comment: to set the proper header for the request. in the post the data should be sent in the request body. so for this request we are setting the `content-type` and informing the server about the incoming data.

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","login.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("lun=myuser1&lp=mellon");
```